# OMNeT++ Simulations go directly to end

Tags: message, omnet++, inet

I've noticed that some INET examples, if I run them, go straight to the end of the simulation.
For example, I run the UdpAppExample.ned (inside the folder inet/examples/inet/udpapp). The Qtenv environment shows up. I set some parameters. Then I press run, and I ***instantly*** receive this message

```
No more events, simulation completed -- at t=4s, event #4
```

But I didn't see the animation of the simulation.

Other examples, like the TcpAppExample.ned (inside folder inet/examples/inet/tcpapp), before finishing make me see the animation of the messages exchange. I see the messages being sent from a node to the other graphically.

Why is that some simulations don't let me see the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are **NOT** running the `General` configuration. Those examples are setup in a way, that you never have to manually enter anything except selecting the appropriate configuration. The `General` configuration is not meant to be run and incomplete.

Comment: It does the same thing even if I run the RequestResponseTraffic Config (UdpAppExample.ned). The BurstyTraffic Config works fine though. Don't know why.